# Django filter from multiple fields with empty input

Tags: python, django, reactjs, filter

I am new to Django and I am right now trying to deal with the issue of filtering based on specific field. React.js is used for the front-end and Django is used as RESTful APIs.

For the front-end, users are allowed to choose to either search based on number or name. The info has been successfully collected. The following code just for better understanding and is incomplete.

```
<input type="text" /><label>Search by number</label>
<input type="text" /><label>Search by name</label>
```

For the backend, response should filter the queryset based on input information, which is either number or name. However, when I went through the document, I noticed that for filtering, all the filtering fields should be provided.

```
Entry.objects.filter(number=123, name="abc")
```

How can I do the filter based on the given info from the front-end, for example, if user chooses to search by name that Django does:

```
Entry.objects.filter(number=123)
```

while if user chooses to search by name, then Django does:

```
Entry.objects.filter(name="abc")
```

I understand that I can actually create two different APIs endpoints, so the number and name won't interfere each other. However, if there are more filter fields, then it is definitely inefficient to write every single API based on each field.

Anyone can help me with this? Please let me know if I explain it clearly or more info should be provided.

Comment: Are you looking to filter by `number` and `name` in a mutually exclusive way, or can a user filter by both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Q` objects to filter results with oring

Something like below

```
from django.db.models import Q
Entry.objects.filter(Q(number=123) | Q(name="abc"))
```

There are more ways to use `Q` objects refer [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).